# Verify whether the following set are subspaces of the vector spaces taken into consideration

Tags: linear-algebra

a){(x, y, z) | z^2 = 1} in R^3 over R
b){f(x) ∈ R^R| f(2) + f(3) = 0} in R^R over R

I dont totally get those 2 :( Can somebody explain me, how to deal with it?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I totally dont get it. I know that i need to check 3 conditions, but i dont really know how to do it. Totally green in subspaces.

Comment: For the first, if $(x,y,z)\in V$ is $c(x,y,z)\in V$ for $c$ an arbitrary scalar?  Notice that $(0,0,1)\in V$.  Is $2(0,0,1)$?

Comment: Yes it is correct for an arbitrary scalar. But what with that vector=0 condition?

Comment: I just get it that if z has to be (0,0,1) or (0,0,-1). So it will never reach 1st condition :D. But what with the other conditions? And whats with the f(x)? f(2+3)=0 from start, but what with other conditions? How i can check it? Sorry for my retardness :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a set $V$ with binary operation $+$ and scalar field $K$ over $V$ with scalar multiplication $\cdot$ which satisfy associativity, commutativity, and distributivity...

$V$ is a vector space over the scalar field $K$ if and only if the following condition is satisfied:

$$u,v\in V,~\text{and}~ \alpha,\beta\in K\implies \alpha\cdot u+\beta\cdot v\in V$$

This is often instead worded as the following three conditions:  $(0\in V),~~(u,v\in V\implies u+v\in V),~~(v\in V~\text{and}~\alpha\in K\implies \alpha\cdot v\in V)$

For the first question, the set of all points in $\Bbb R^3$ such that $z^2=1$

Check the first condition: is the "zero" element (*in this case $(0,0,0)$*) in our set?  Is $(0,0,0)\in V$?  I.e. does $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ satisfy $z^2=1$?

> No, since $(0,0,0)$ has the square of the third term equal to zero, not one, it doesn't satisfy the defining property to be in the set.

Alternatively, check the second condition.  If $(x,y,z)\in V$ and $(x',y',z')\in V$ does that imply that $(x,y,z)+(x',y',z')\in V$?  Try to find a counter example or give an arbitrary argument why it has to always be true.

> No again, since $(0,0,1)\in V$ and so is $(0,0,1)$, but $(0,0,1)+(0,0,1)=(0,0,2)$ is not in $V$ since the square of the third entry is four, not one, and therefore it doesn't satisfy the defining property to be in the set.

Alternatively again, check the third condition.  If $(x,y,z)\in V$ and $\alpha\in \Bbb R$, is $\alpha(x,y,z)=(\alpha x,\alpha y,\alpha z)\in V$?  Again, find a counterexample or come up with a general argument why it has to always be true.

> Again, No, since $(0,0,1)\in V$ and $5\in \Bbb R$ but $5(0,0,1)=(0,0,5)$ is not in $V$ since the third entry squared is equal to 25, not one and therefore it doesn't satisfy the defining property to be in the set.

If the answer to any of the above is no, then it is not a vector space.  If you find even one no, you don't need to check any of the other properties about it.

---

For the second approach similarly.  Check each individual property or the combined property I already mentioned.

If $f$ and $g$ are both functions satisfying $f(2)+f(3)=0$ and $g(2)+g(3)=0$, will $\alpha\cdot f+\beta\cdot g$ be a function with the same property?

Is $(\alpha\cdot f+\beta\cdot g)(2)+(\alpha\cdot f+\beta\cdot g)(3)=0$?

> $(\alpha\cdot f+\beta\cdot g)(2)+(\alpha\cdot f+\beta\cdot g)(3)=\alpha (\underbrace{f(2)+f(3)}_{\to 0})+\beta(\underbrace{g(2)+g(3)}_{\to 0})=\dots$ where we can replace those two underbraced expressions with zero because of our assumption that $f$ and $g$ are both elements in our set $V$.

Comment: Ok, so if i can use your help again.

I'm checking 1st condition about 0.
f(2+3)=0, so this is satysfying me.
2nd condition
f(2)+f(3)+f(2)+f(3)=f(2)+f(3), so again this is true.
3nd condition is true too, cause x*0 is always true for all values of x, am i right?

Comment: Noone ever said that $f(2+3)=0$.  The condition was $f$ is an element of our set of functions iff $f(2\color{red}{)+f(}3)=0$.  Examples of such functions would be $f(x)=0, f(x)=2.5-x, f(x)=x^2-5x+6,\dots$

Comment: Yea,yea my fault. But is that make that way f(f(2)+f(3))=0? This is correct?

Comment: Why are you trying to take the function of a function?  No... and furthermore, $f(0)$ doesn't have to be equal to zero...  Lets take this one step at a time...What would the "zero element" be for our set of functions?

Comment: So we from begining know that we have 0 in our subspace, right? Cause f(2)+f(3)=0? Ok if that is true. If we are adding f(2)+f(3)=0 with g(2)+g(3)=0, nothing will change, so this is true too? I dont really know. Have i to find function g(x) that will not satisfy my space? Or have i try to with some examples like that f(2) = -1 f(3) = 1  g(2) = -3 g(3) = 3 that will not work or will work?

Comment: "We have 0 in our subspace" What is zero to you in this context?  A number?  Or a function?  The zero in $f(2)+f(3)=0$ is **not** the zero we are wanting to talk about here because the zero in $f(2)+f(3)=0$ is a number.  Our set is a set of **functions**.  Is there a "zero element" in our set of **functions**?

Comment: Okay, zero is a number from function, like we need search f(x)=0 but how? We have only f(2)=-f(3) and to be honest i have no clue here. I get it with an only numbers, but functions are really weird for me.

Comment: The *zerofunction*  $Zero(x)$ is the function that maps any input to the number zero.  $Zero(x)$ does indeed satisfy $Zero(2)+Zero(3)=0$ because $Zero(2)+Zero(3)=0+0=0$, so our set of functions does indeed have a zero element.  Now, how about adding things.  If we know that $f$ is a function such that $f(2)+f(3)=0$ and $g$ is a function such that $g(2)+g(3)=0$, what about the function $(f+g)$?  Is $(f+g)(2)+(f+g)(3)=0$?  Why?

Comment: What extacly is (f+g)? I think i get that f(2) in that case is different to g(2) but 0+0=0 same in case with 3. So nothing will change and that condition is correct?

Comment: Given a function $f$ and a function $g$, the function $(f+g)$ is the function such that $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$

Comment: So that is true, i know that can be trivial but i totally dont get how to prove it. I think that a(f+g)(2)+b(f+g)(3) will be also true, but how can i prove it?

Comment: Look again at the second half of my post.  You assume that $f$ and $g$ are elements of $V$ and you check to see whether or not any linear combination of $f$ and $g$ will satisfy the properties needed to be considered an element of $V$.  The second half of my post explains already how to prove it.

Comment: Guy, u are the best <3! I know really get it :D You have made imposiblle thing :D Sorry for wasting your time, really great explanation now <3.